# Kendo : How do i keep the toolbar when i save and restore a grid state?

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I kept the title generic because i don't care if the answer I get is in jquery, javascript, or specifically to MVC.

I have this code to save and load a grid:

```
$("#save").click(function() {
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

var state = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());


$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/ebol/savegrid",
    data: {
        data: state
    }
});
});

$("#load").click(function () {
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

$.ajax({
    url: "/ebol/loadgrid",
    success: function (options) {
        if (options) {
            grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options));
        }
    }
});
});
```

The problem:  I can save a grid's state (which includes column order, filters etc) but when i go to restore it with the load button, the grid's command column vanishes.
[image]

How do i preserve these buttons as well during the restore?

Comment: Can you show us how you are creating the grid and toolbar please?

Comment: standard kendo mvc grid.  Nothing special.

Comment: Fair enough. The [setOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions) documentation has some advice specifically relating to the MVC wrapper. I suspect that's relevant to your problem.

Comment: I'm tossing you some upvotes for your help.  The problem was in fact caused by us using an mvc wrapper.  It doesn't render the toolbar area when layouts are applied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another of our developers who was working on this exact issue on another page solved this one for me.  You need to detach the toolbar before loading the grid settings.  It seems hacky to me but according to Kendo, saving and loading settings is unsupported so this is the best we have.  My revised code:

```
    $("#load").click(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ebol/loadgrid",
        success: function(state) {
            if (state) {
                state = JSON.parse(state);
                let toolBar = $("#grid .k-grid-toolbar").detach();
                grid.setOptions(state);
                $("#grid .k-grid-toolbar").replaceWith(toolBar);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: One and only way to awoid unnecessary
`<span class="k-edit" width="100%">`
blocks.